# Can someone clearly explain the difference between attributes and variables in Python classes?

Tags: python-3.x, class, variables, attributes, instance-variables

In this code:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, fname, lname):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname

student_1 = Student('bob', 'the builder')
student_2 = Student('perry', 'the platipus')
```

Are .fname, .lname an instance variable or an instance attribute? or are they the same thing? It seems like online videos/tutorials use variable and attribute interchangeably and it confuses me a lot.

Comment: Instance variables and attributes are the same thing. But your `student_1` and `student_2` are not Students.

Comment: yep, forgot to call the class student. Are class variables/attributes interchangeable too then?

Comment: Class variables and class attributes are the same thing.

Comment: thx for the clarification~